# Can you benefit from the Fencing Grace feat while wielding a buckler?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, damage, ability-scores, shield

**Fencing Grace**:

> When wielding a rapier one-handed, you can add your Dexterity modifier
> instead of your Strength modifier to that weapon’s damage. The rapier
> must be one appropriate for your size. You do not gain this benefit
> while fighting with two weapons or using flurry of blows, or *anytime
> another hand is otherwise occupied*.

**Buckler**:

> *This small metal shield is worn strapped to your forearm*. You can use
> a bow or crossbow without penalty while carrying it. You can also use
> your shield arm to wield a weapon (whether you are using an offhand
> weapon or using your off hand to help wield a two-handed weapon), but
> you take a –1 penalty on attack rolls while doing so. This penalty
> stacks with those that may apply for fighting with your off hand and
> for fighting with two weapons. In any case, if you use a weapon in
> your off hand, you lose the buckler’s Armor Class bonus until your
> next turn.

Does using a **buckler** count as using a hand that is *'otherwise occupied'* in determining gaining the benefits from the **Fencing Grace** feat?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## You can use a buckler with Fencing Grace.

If we look at [Slashing Grace](https://aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Slashing%20Grace), we can see that it has the same line:

> You do not gain this benefit while fighting with two weapons or using flurry of blows, or any time another hand is otherwise occupied.

Additionally, there is an [FAQ](https://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1gw#v5748eaic9tmm) for Slashing Grace that states:

> Slashing Grace: In the 2nd printing errata, what exactly does it mean that “You do not gain this benefit while fighting with two weapons or using flurry of blows, or any time another hand is otherwise occupied?” Can I use a shield? **What about a buckler?** Can I use flurry of blows? Brawler’s flurry? Two-weapon fighting? Spell combat? Attack with natural weapons? What if I throw the weapon? What about swordmaster’s flair?
>
> *Slashing Grace does not allow most shields, **but bucklers work because they don’t occupy the hand.*** Flurry of blows, brawler’s flurry, two-weapon fighting, and spell combat all don’t work with Slashing Grace. Attacking with natural weapons beyond the weapon you chose for Slashing Grace also does not work. Slashing Grace only works with melee attacks, not thrown attacks with a melee weapon. Swordmaster’s flair should have a sentence added to it that says “Carrying a swordmaster’s flair counts as having that hand free for the purpose of abilities that require a free hand, though you still can’t hold another object in that hand.”

Since it shares the same language as Fencing Grace, this should be true for Fencing Grace as well. Therefore, you can use a buckler with Fencing Grace.